Where are WiFi passwords stored in Ubuntu 24.04?
In the past, WiFi passwords can be found in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/. With the new Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat, that folder is empty (even as I am using home WiFi now to post this question).
So the question, where are WiFi passwords stored now?
PS: I also have active Wireguard VPN connections made via the NetworkManager GUI. The /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN folder is also empty.

Did you save the connection settings for only your user? Then IIRC it gets saved in your keying

The connection is available to all users.

The wifi passwords are now stored in .yaml files in /etc/netplan

Just wondering if they're stored in plain text?

They are likely stored in plain text but they might need admin/root privileges to view the files

You're right. they are right there. Yes, stored in plaintext and the permissions of the yaml files are -rw------- 1 root root. Thanks for that.

I wonder why they are stored as plaintext instead of a (salt+)hash?

@qwr they were stored in plain text when they where in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections but you needed admin privileges to read/see any file in that directory

It would be hard to use the encrypted password. If you have root privileges you would be able to decrypt them anyway, since the are to be used unencrypted.

@rapto and they may be able to be viewed in Network Manager settings without added privileges
